# LiveChatMessages API YouTube возвращает null

Tags: php, парсер, youtube-api

Пытаюсь получить сообщения с чата прямой трансляции с помощью GET-запроса.

```
$json_result = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=$videoId&part=snippet&key=$api_key");
// $videoId и $api_key верны, тут ошибок нет.
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(json_decode($json_result));
echo '</pre>';
```

В ответе получаю `NULL`, подскажите в чем ошибка или каким методом можно получить сообщения из чата трансляции YouTube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому-то будет полезно, решил вопрос через `cURL` вместо `file_get_contents`.

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=$LiveChatId&part=snippet%2CauthorDetails&maxResults=200&key=$api_key");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'JeezLand API');
$json_results = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$json_decode_results = json_decode($json_results);
foreach($json_decode_results as $json_decode_result){
    foreach($json_decode_result as $result){
        /* echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($result);
        echo '</pre>'; */
        echo $result->authorDetails->displayName.' -> '.$result->snippet->displayMessage.'<br />';
    }
}
```